# How do I set a bookmark in Zend Studio?

Tags: php, eclipse, zend-studio

In all instructions I can find, including the offline help, say to right click on a line in the editor and choose 'Add bookmark', but I have no such command in my context menu. So, how do I add a bookmark?

The [Eclipse help topic](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/gettingStarted/qs-37-3c.htm) is useless, as it describes an entirely different context menu to the one I get when I right click. And F2 does nothing, maybe sometimes shows function docs.

Comment: Have you tried [this keyboard shortcut](http://blog.boringguys.com/2006/07/zend-studio-tip-of-day-bookmarks.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is explained [here](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/gettingStarted/qs-37-3c.htm), use Edit -> Add Bookmark for an editor file.

What the help says is that if the cursor is positions over the marker bar, you can right click and it will show "Add BookMark..." The marker bar is the bar on the left edge of the editor where you would place breakpoints.

Comment: The context menu could be quite different in the PHP editor and because of a number of factors, but the Add Bookmark is there in a standard Java editor. I have not actually tried it with the Zend Studio and it's possible they have done something to suppress it from the context menu. In any case Edit -> Add Bookmark should work. And if you want a key binding, you can go to Preferences -> General -> Keys and type in "bookmark" and then bind a desired key to "Add bookmark".

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to Keys @Francois, but unfortunately even after setting F2 to add bookmark, it doesn't. I will follow up with Zend support.